# json_decoded hidden POST value doesn't return anything (or returns empty)

Tags: php, json, hidden-field

***SOLUTION:***

---

As var_dump shows, the quotes were swapped with ascii (?)

```
    'emails2bsent' => string '[&#34;email1@gmail.com&#34;,&#34;email2@gmail.com&#34;]'
```

Running preg_replace and forcing them being changed back to regular quotes solved the problem:

```
$_POST = preg_replace("/&#34;/", "\"", $_POST);
$json = $_POST['emails2bsent'];
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
    0 => string 'email1@gmail.com' (length=23)
    1 => string 'email2@gmail.com' (length=23)

array (size=2)
    0 => string 'email1@gmail.com' (length=23)
    1 => string 'email2@gmail.com' (length=23)
```

---

**The actual problem:**

json_decode on POST hidden value.

I am sending an array of emails via form's hidden field:

```
<input name="emails2bsent" type="hidden" value='<?php echo json_encode($emails2bsent)?>' />
```

and then while trying to get the array back:

```
$emails2bsent = json_decode($_POST['emails2bsent'], true);
```

or

```
$emails2bsent = json_decode($_POST['emails2bsent']);
```

it returns nothing.
What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

The print_r output on the destination page shows these:

```
Array
(
    [reminder] => Some copy goes here,
    [button] => Send
    [go3] => three
    [reminder_ID] => 198
    [emails2bsent] => ["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]
)
```

When I want to access *$_POST['emails2bsent']*

`echo($_POST['emails2bsent']);`

I can do that, too.
It just cannot be decoded. I am stuck on this one cuz I wanna understand why this isn't working. I would have programmed it around long time ago but I just cannot let it go without knowing why it's not working..

May I know WHY I got two minus votes?
For asking questions?

---

**Re: ADyson**

The input field of my form before sending it:

```
<input name="emails2bsent" type="hidden" value="[&quot;email1@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;email2@gmail.com&quot;]">
```

The code I use to view the passed data:

```
pre($_POST);
echo($_POST['emails2bsent']);
$out = json_decode($_POST['emails2bsent'], true);
echo '<br>out: ' . $out;
```

The output on the page:

```
    Array
(
    [reminder] => The copy
    [button] => send
    [go3] => three
    [reminder_ID] => 198
    [emails2bsent] => ["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]
)

["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]
out:
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` , what is the form's html code?

Comment: What does the `$emails2bsent` variable looks like (`var_dump($emails2bsent)`).

Comment: If json_decode() returns null it indicates a failure to decode the data. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php might help you find out why. As the others said, you should also check that the raw input values contain what you are expecting. From the minimal code sample provided, we have no way to know what is going wrong - we need further information. Thanks.

Comment: htmlspecialchars didn't do anything :(

However the json-last-error shows error number 4. I really don't get this JSON thing...

Comment: JSON is just a way of formatting and structuring data in a textual format. It's nothing terribly complicated. Anyway, error code 4 indicates a syntax error in the JSON (you can look this up in the docs, or use `json_last_error_msg()` to get a text description of the error.  Now, you say that your `$_POST["emails2bsent"]` value contains `["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]`, but as [this demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed35f04be6b8349e77ee7169fc654ca235f9192c) shows, that data would not cause json_decode() to crash. The data you've provided doesn't reproduce the issue

Comment: P.S. "WHY I got two minus votes?" ...hover your mouse over the downvote button on any question and you can see reasons why downvotes can be (or are supposed to be) given. So no, not just for asking questions, but more likely for asking not-very-good questions. As we pointed out earlier, you didn't give us enough information to help you. And now you have given us information, it doesn't fit with what you're telling us the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to HTML-encode the JSON:

```
<input name="emails2bsent"
       type="hidden"
       value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($emails2bsent)); ?>">
```

Valid JSON could result in invalid HTML and browser might not post it correctly.

Comment: Nobody knows since comments are not answered, however, encoding, especially doublequotes, should generally be done. +1